# Trying to create a for loop that checks my file name for backslashes and replaces them with forward slashes

Tags: string, for-loop

As mentioned in the title I am trying to create a function to parse through a string, which would be my file name and return another version but with all the backslashes replaced with forward slashes. My file names are saved with backslashes instead of forward slashes and thus does not work unless I use 'r' before the file name. I know this is an easy workaround but I am now interested in defining a function to fix this solution.

Here is the code I am attempting to use:

```
backslash = '\''

def parser(string, character):
    letters = []
    for i in string:
        if i != character:
            letters.append(i)
        else:
            letters.append('/')

    return letters
```

This is my output, which is obviously wrong. Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix my issue or a way to circumvent this?

```
[B',
 'o',
 'b',
 '\\',
 'g',
 'o',
 'e',
 's',
 '\\',
 's',
 'h',
 'o',
 'p',
 'p',
 'i',
 'n',
 'g']
```

p.s. If it makes any difference I am using windows 10 and microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The backslash ( `\`) character is used to escape characters that
>   otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself,
>   or the quote character

Your backslash character is holding `'`, which is not correct. For your variable to hold the backslash literal itself, you must use two backslash as given in below code.

The following code parses correctly -

```
backslash = '\\'

def parser(string, character):
    letters = []
    for i in string:
        if i != character:
            letters.append(i)
        else:
            letters.append('/')

    return letters

# The address location to be parsed
address_with_backslash = 'C:\\user\\something\\InvestingScientist'

print("Original address : " + address_with_backslash)
print("\nAddress after Parsing : " + "".join(parser(address_with_backslash,backslash)))
```

Output :

```
Original address : C:\user\something\InvestingScientist

Address after Parsing : C:/user/something/InvestingScientist
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @InvestingScientist No problem! You function was correct by itself. You were just passing the character incorrectly. Remember, you need to escape the backslash escape character itself (hence two backslash)  whenever you want to use it.

Comment: When you mentioned it I did remember a class it was mentioned in but that was a while ago now! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

backslash is the escape character so if you want to have a literal backslash in a string you need to use a double-backslash

Heres the solution:

```
backslash = '\\'

def parser(string, character):
    letters = []
    for i in string:
        if i != character:
            letters.append(i)
        else:
            letters.append('/')

    return letters
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help